# controller is not working with route functionality

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularjs tech. I have implemented one registration function in my project.

I have created one js file for routing and controller functionality in my project and its working fine, If i will do separate router and controller file then I am application is failing.

I need to do separate file for the router and controller.

Below is my code in one file.

app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('crasApp', [ 'ngRoute' ]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "./views/xyz.html",
        controller : "searchCtrl"
    }).when("/registration", {
        templateUrl : "./views/abc.html",
        controller : "MainCtrl"
    }).when("/view", {
        templateUrl : "./views/viewsdata.html",
        controller : "overViewCtrl"
    });
});
app
        .controller(
                "MainCtrl",
                function($scope, $http) {       
         console.log("Hi");
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="crasApp">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
<!-- Use Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/abn-stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
<script src="./javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="./javascripts/jquery/jquery.min-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="./javascripts/angular/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="./javascripts/angular/angular.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="./javascripts/controllers/app.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="./javascripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script> -->
<script src="./javascripts/router/router.js"></script>

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

</head>
<div ng-view></div>

</html>
```

xyz.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="crasApp">
<head>
<!-- Use Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/abn-stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/ngDatepicker.css">
<script src="./javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="./javascripts/jquery/jquery.min-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="./javascripts/angular/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="./javascripts/controllers/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 Hi
</body>
<html>
```

So, Its working file if I am using one app.js file

I want to do seprate router and controller file.

router functionality i moved into different file and its working router functionality but not working controller functionality..

Separate router file as below.

router.js

```
var app = angular.module('crasApp', [ 'ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "./views/retrieveTerminationReason.html",
        /*controller : "searchCtrl"*/
    }).when("/registration", {
        templateUrl : "./views/registration.html",
        /*controller : "MainCtrl"*/
    }).when("/view", {
        templateUrl : "./views/forbearanceRegistartionOverview.html",
        /*controller : "overViewCtrl"*/
    });
});
```

app.js as a controller

```
var app = angular.module('crasApp', []);

app
        .controller(
                'MainCtrl',
                function($scope, $http) {
                    console.log("Hi");
});
```

Please any one can help on this part.

Comment: while this probably *appears* to be working, you have some issues that you should address.  Notably, the `template` **is not a full HTML document**, you should remove the `html`, `head`, all the `script` tags, etc. from that document.  Also, when using `controller:` in the route, you should not duplicate it by also using `ng-controller` in the template file.  Beyond that, the answer @Brian provided is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the issue**
when you're using `var app = angular.module('crasApp', [ 'ngRoute']);` in your route.js file you are initializing new module NOT adding config to existing module!

the best approach for structuring an Angular App is NOT using variable you can call your module in a different way like:

**app.js**

```
var MODULE_NAME = 'crasApp'
angular.module(MODULE_NAME, ['ngRoute']);
```

to create controller **controllers.js**

```
angular.module(MODULE_NAME).controller('MainCtrl',function($scope, $http) {  //Note removing the dependencies array
       console.log("Hi");
 });
```

to create config  **routes.js**

```
angular.module(MODULE_NAME).config(function($routeProvider) { //Note removing the dependencies array
$routeProvider.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "./views/retrieveTerminationReason.html",
    /*controller : "searchCtrl"*/
})
```

in your **index.html**

```
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
 </head>
```

**Note** you don't need ng-controller directive in your HTML because defining it in routes is enough

**separating services**

create services.js for example

```
angular.module(MODULE_NAME).factory('Users',function($http,$q) {
  return {
    getUsers:function(){
      var def = $q.defer();
      $http({url:'URL_HERE',method:'GET'}).then(function(res){
        def.resolve(res)
      },function(err){
        def.reject(err);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

**using in controller**

```
angular.module(MODULE_NAME).controller('MainCtrl',function($scope, Users) {  //Note Users is the name of the factory created above
   Users.getUsers().then(function(res){
     $scope.users=res;
   },function(err){
     $scope.error = err;
   })
});
```

Comment: Its working above implementation. thanks for response.

Comment: How can we split service js. I am using REST get and post service in my controller . How can we split service from controller.

Comment: Can we use .service instead of the .factory ?

Comment: Yes sure but it will be little bit different in implementation

Comment: How can we implement ui.router' instead of ngRoute. Can you please provide example based on the above angularjs router.

Answer (score 2):

In router.js, change `var app = angular.module('crasApp', [ 'ngRoute'])` to `var app = angular.module('crasApp')`.

Also, in app.js, your declaration should be: `var app = angular.module('crasApp', ['ngRoute']);`. Since you have a single module, 'crasApp', you must declare it's dependencies when you declare the module itself.

What you have currently is re-creating the module vs. appending functionality.

Also, be sure to include your router.js as well in your HTML .